# How to pass information from controller which role has been succeed

Tags: c#, .net-core, controller, authorization

I am using .NET Core with Vue.JS

I want to know in my view by which role user is verified

**What I have now**

**Controller**

```
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.R)]
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.F)]
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.Admin)]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("IsAdmin")]
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.Admin)]
public IActionResult IsAdmin()
{            
    return Ok(true);
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("IsFull")]
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.F)]
public IActionResult IsFull()
{
    return Ok(true);
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("IsRead")]
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.R)]
public IActionResult IsRead()
{
    return Ok(true);
}
```

**View**

```
let vm = this;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/IsAdmin',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        vm.isAdmin = true;
    },
    error: function (result) {
    },
    async: false
});

jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/IsFull',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        vm.isFull = true;
    },
    error: function (result) {
    },
    async: false
});

jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/IsRead',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        vm.isRead = true;
    },
    error: function (result) {
    },
    async: false
});
```

I know this looks terrible and probably it is terrible approach, but I don't have any better idea.

I addition. For handling roles I am using custom `AuthorizationHandler` because I need to combine `RolesPrefix` from configuration.

**Custom AuthorizationHandler**

```
public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext authContext)
{
    var succeed = false;

    var pendingRequirements = authContext.PendingRequirements.ToList();

    var requiredRoles = new List<RoleRequirement>();

    foreach (var requirement in pendingRequirements)
    {
        requiredRoles.AddRange(((RolesAuthorizationRequirement)requirement).AllowedRoles.Select(x => new RoleRequirement(x)).ToList());
    }

    foreach (var role in requiredRoles)
    {
        if (role is RoleRequirement requirement)
        {
            var prefix = _configuration.GetValue<string>("RolesPrefix");

            if (authContext.User.IsInRole(prefix + requirement.Role))
            {
                succeed = true;
            }
        }
    };

    if (succeed)
    {
        MakeRequirementsSucceed(authContext);
    }         

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private static void MakeRequirementsSucceed(AuthorizationHandlerContext authContext)
{
    authContext.PendingRequirements.ToList().ForEach(x => authContext.Succeed(x));
}
```

**What I think will be better**

```
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.R)]
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.F)]
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.Admin)]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var prefix = GetPrefixFromConfig();
    var isAdmin = User.IsInRole(prefix + Roles.Admin);
    var isFull = User.IsInRole(prefix + Roles.F);
    var isRead = User.IsInRole(prefix + Roles.R);
    
    return View(new { isAdmin, isFull, isRead });
}
```

Obviously provided example (pseudocoded) is not working due to `IsInRole` method always return null for some reason.

Could you show and expain to me better solution for this problem? I would appreciate your answer

Comment: How does your custom AuthorizationHandler look? For the IsInRole method to work, you need to add the roles as claims to the ClaimsPrincipal

Comment: @fbede I added code that u are asking for. Could you please provide an example code of that what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

As solution. I used [How to check if user is member of group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53191160/how-to-check-if-user-is-member-of-group) accepted answer by Nan Yu and then:

```
var prefix = _configuration.GetValue<string>("RolesPrefix");
var isAdmin = User.IsInGroup(prefix + Roles.Admin);
var isRead = User.IsInGroup(prefix + Roles.R);
var isFull = User.IsInGroup(prefix + Roles.F);
```

This will only work for WindowsAuthentication (which I am using)