# Best solution for login with Ldap Active Directory in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory

I am implementing a web application project in ASP.NET Core. I want to create authentication for our users. What is the best third party for login with LDAP Active Directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707820/how-to-use-active-directory-authentication-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want seamless login (where the end user does not need to enter their username and passowrd), you don't need any third-party library for this. This is called "Windows Authentication", and it is already supported. [See the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to learn how to use it, depending in your server OS. It is easiest to setup in IIS on Windows, but as of ASP.NET Core 3.0, it is also supported on Linux and MacOS.

The users must already be logged into their computers with the account that they need to use on your website. For IE and Chrome, your website will need to be added to the Trusted Sites (in Internet Options) on the client computers. If your users use Firefox, it has its own `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` setting.