# Asp.net core with Docker Authentication

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

What is the best practice for Authenticating against a domain (Active Directory) for a valid user?

Once authenticated, how do my controllers know the user has been authenticated (if they aren't then we ask to relogin)

I read many articles on the web and i am a little confused. Some guidance would be helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Active Directory Authentication in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707820/how-to-use-active-directory-authentication-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: From what I read that Windows Authentication can't be done from Docker. So my options are to use LDAP authentication.

Comment: That's exactly the second option in the answer to the question I linked. If you can't use `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` (for instance you are on linux based containers), use `Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard`.