# How to authenticate a User in .Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages web app using local Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, active-directory, ldap

Good afternoon, 
I am developing a web application using .Net Core 3.1 and Razor Pages. I have started developing the application using Azure AD to authenticate the user that signs into my application using the project creation wizard. This approach is very easy and user friendly but unfortunately my organization wants the application to authenticate the user by using the local AD server and not the Azure AD one.

I have been googling around but have not found the best way to achieve an authentication such as the one provided by Azure AD but using the local AD server. But haven't found the right literature for this. Could anyone please point me towards the right direction please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `wants the application to authenticate the user by using the local AD server` Please check this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53707820/how-to-use-active-directory-authentication-in-asp-net-core

Comment: I gave a look at this thread already and this is what is pointing me towards the use of novell's library to manage the authentication. In my solution I actually created a LdapAuthenticationService and initialized the service in the ConfigurationServices mStartup methos as described this article: [link](https://nicolas.guelpa.me/blog/2017/02/15/dotnet-core-ldap-authentication.html)

The point that is giving me headaches is how to add the Razor Pages for the user to pass his/hers authentication details and login.