# Can ASP.NET Core Identification & Authorization map to Active Directory?

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory

Reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) it looks like the ASP.NET Core I&A system can not use ActiveDirectory. And that same page says for the API part of the web service, that should use ActiveDirectory.

Since I don't want users to have to create 2 logins, is there any way to point the ASP.NET Core I&A system to call down to Active Directory?

And if not, is there a good example about how to use ActiveDirectory for the forms part of an ASP.NET Core app?

Comment: ASP.NET Core Identity is very flexible, so you can build a custom provider working with AD (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49682644/335858) and its linked questions). Custom providers look scary because of the number of methods that need to be implemented, but in the end they aren't too bad, because most methods are simple.

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko I think something like this would be so common that someone has already done this. But I can't find an instance.